# Clear the edit text in a custom list row

Tags: android, listview, button, android-edittext, baseadapter

I have a custom list row which has two `TextView` and one `EditText` .
I want to clear the text typed in `EditText` of all the list rows on a `Button` click which is a `reset button`.
The `Button` is in an `Activity`
Can anyone suggest me a way I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is not clear at first, if you mean a system like listview or scroller when you say custom list row, then while on click of button do the following

1. Get all the child from the view
2. loop through each child, finding EditText inside each child view
3. Simply setText to empty.

I hope got your question right, else please put some code here.

Comment: yes exactly,
can you tell me how to get all the child from the view?

Comment: Use getChildCount to get number of child from a view, then use this number to loop and find every child by using getchildat method, once you get the child use findviewbyid

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to clear the editText
YourEditText.setText("");